# How to create a unique URL for a unique information in a float tab on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I am creating a page but there is a problem with how to make the URL directly to the unique information on the page.
For example: [page](http://katejieyudesign.com/synopsys/snug-world-landing-page-test/snug-world.html)
I would like to make the URL directly to the day 2 track 2. How could I do it? I tried to add the ID name in the URL. But only http://katejieyudesign.com/synopsys/snug-world-landing-page-test/snug-world.html#day1 works.

Does it have a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And, It is good to show us the code that you tried / didn't work. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66356753/edit) your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that until you click on the actual buttons, the data for the different days is hidden (i.e. `display:none`), as well as tracks > 1.
Day 1 tab is by default active, so you can navigate to it, track 1 can also be navigated to as it is by default active and visible.  Navigating directly to any other of the bookmarks is not possible without first clicking on their buttons to make them active (and thus visible).